# Page_Unload not firing when using response.redirect(somepage,true)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm closing a WCF endpoint in the page_unload of an asp.net page, when using response.redirect() the page_unload event doesn't fire and i'm ending up with ophanned endpoint references.

I thought the page_unload should fire everytime.

Anyone shed any light.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.Redirect(somepage, false)
```

When you pass `true` instead of `false` you are indicating that you wish to terminate the execution of the page.  By passing `false` you are indicating that you wish the page to finish processing before redirecting the client.